# How to enable GZip compression for Gitlab Pages?

Tags: caching, http-headers, gitlab, compression, gzip

When using **Gitlab Pages** to render my site which is slow in page-ranking. I can't find any solution on how to do following in GitLab (*non-enterprise version*)

1. Specify `HTTP Cache Headers` for various page resources like for an image, so that it can be cached.
2. Specify/Enable compression for GZip as page-ranking mentions compression disabled in gitlab.io.

Answer (score 5):

1. It looks like specifying HTTP Cache Headers is still not possible. But at least they have hardcoded *"max-age=600"* for all the resources [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/merge_requests/35).
2. You can compress contents of your **public** folder via *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

   script:

   - npm install
   - npm run build
   - gzip -k -6 -r public

Comment: Alpine's will fail because it doesn't have the -r option. I used regular node:12 that uses debian and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

GitLab has support for serving compressed assets if you pre-compress them in the `pages` CI Job already. [See the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#serving-compressed-assets).

Note that you can and also should use `brotli` compression as it's optimized for web content and supported by most modern browsers.

There is also a suggested snippet for your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
pages:
  # Other directives
  script:
    # Build the public/ directory first
    - find public -type f -regex '.*\.\(htm\|html\|txt\|text\|js\|css\)$' -exec gzip -f -k {} \;
    - find public -type f -regex '.*\.\(htm\|html\|txt\|text\|js\|css\)$' -exec brotli -f -k {} \;
```

I haven't found a way of influencing cache behavior. I am also looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Enable GZip compression for GitLab Pages

If you add the precompressed `.gz` versions of the files of your static site, then `nginx` can serve them instead of the regular ones. Add this line to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .temp
    - cp -r * .temp
    - mv .temp public
    - gzip -k -9 $(find public -type f)
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

This command compresses all files found in the `public` directory with the maximum compression ratio.